# "tmux has-session" search is prefix-matching

Tags: tmux

I'm trying to determine if a tmux session exists by `has-session` command.

If I have a session named *abcdf*:

```
adm@VirtualBox:/$ tmux -V
tmux 2.1
adm@VirtualBox:/$ tmux ls
abcdf: 1 windows (created Fri Feb  3 16:19:20 2017) [237x56] (attached)
```

`has-session` command will return the session named **a**,**ab**,**abc**,**abcd**,**abcdf** is exist (error code=0)

```
adm@VirtualBox:/$ tmux has -t a
adm@VirtualBox:/$ echo $?
0
adm@VirtualBox:/$ tmux has -t ab
adm@VirtualBox:/$ echo $?
0
adm@VirtualBox:/$ tmux has -t abc
adm@VirtualBox:/$ echo $?
0
adm@VirtualBox:/$ tmux has -t abcd
adm@VirtualBox:/$ echo $?
0
adm@VirtualBox:/$ tmux has -t abcdf
adm@VirtualBox:/$ echo $?
0
adm@VirtualBox:/$
```

and the following is not exist (error code=1)

```
adm@VirtualBox:/$ tmux has -t b
can't find session b
adm@VirtualBox:/$ echo $?
1
adm@VirtualBox:/$ tmux has -t bc
can't find session bc
adm@VirtualBox:/$ echo $?
1
adm@VirtualBox:/$ tmux has -t bcd
can't find session bcd
adm@VirtualBox:/$ echo $?
1
```

It seems like this command will match the sessions by prefix-matching, is this correct? How do I search the session exact the name I want?

Comment: `tmux list-session` and parse it with `egrep` that is more controllable in term of parsing?

Comment: @Alex Yes, I currently use `tmux ls -F "#{session_name}"|grep -Fx $session >/dev/null` to search, but I'm still curious about this behavior since its manpage says: **Report an error and exit with 1 if the specified session does not exist.**

Comment: I agree that mapage has too broad description and leave a space for assumptions that's why I switched to parse `list-session` too

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The solution is to use = e.g.

-t=sessionname

This does an exact match.

(Having the same issue today and found via: https://github.com/tmux/tmux/issues/346)